# How do I center a textbox in a form with HTML/CSS, if I use padding?

Tags: html, css

I've been looking everywhere but I can't find this, so this may be a stupid question.

Basically, I have a textbox that I want to center within my page. However, I use padding inside the textbox, so the text isn't right next to the border.

How do I do this?

The website in question: http://prntscr.com/c2m93u
As you can see, the amount of distance between the left & right side isn't the same. This occurs because I use padding.

My code:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="Gebruikersnaam", id="TextField" style="width:100%;height:25px;background-color:black;color:white;border:0px;margin:auto;padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px;">
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. Please don't use inline styles like this. 2. The solution is probably `box-sizing: border-box;`.

Comment: Yeah, I try to use CSS as much as I can but just for debugging I used this. This worked, thank you <3 - If you put it as an answer I will mark it as answered since I can't seem to be able to do it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box`. That way, the total width of the element will include the padding of the element. See [Box Model on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
 <div>
 <input type="text" name="username" value="Gebruikersnaam", id="TextField">
</div>
```

CSS

```
  *
  {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
div
{
  width:100vw;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:rgba(70,70,70,1);
  padding:15px;
}
input[type='text']
{
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  height:25px;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  border:0px;
}
```

FIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/uo30v0jp/